# CMake add_custom_target depending on whole project being built

Tags: cmake

I want to add a test target that is dependant on the whole of a project being built successfully, without re-specifying dependencies on all the libraries or executables.

I would write this in make as:

```
all: foo bar

foo: ...
bar: ...

test: all
    test.sh
```

test.sh implicitly uses foo and bar and wants them to be up to date.

This is how I would expect to specify this in cmake.

```
add_library(foo ...)
add_executable(bar ...)

add_custom_target(test test.sh
              DEPENDS all
)
```

However this does not work as there is no all target.

Is there a way to specify this? Or is there a variable that expands to all the targets I am trying to build?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 2.8 CMake does not provide a variable that holds a list of all targets. The best you can do is to override the built-in commands `add_library` and `add_executable` with custom macros that call the built-in ones and keep track of all defined targets in a variable.

You can even use the same names for your custom macros. That way you do not have to make changes to all the existing `add_library` and `add_executable` calls. The original built-in commands are prefixed with an underscore if you override any of them:

```
set (_allTargets "")

macro(add_library _target)
    _add_library (${_target} ${ARGN})
    list (APPEND _allTargets ${_target})
endmacro()

macro(add_executable _target)
    _add_executable (${_target} ${ARGN})
    list (APPEND _allTargets ${_target})
endmacro()

add_library(liba STATIC liba.cpp)
add_executable(main liba main.cpp)

add_custom_target(test "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.sh")

add_dependencies(test ${_allTargets})
```

Also note that you cannot add a target dependency to a custom target with the `DEPENDS` option. `DEPENDS` may only reference existing files or files generated with `add_custom_command(...)` in the same directory. To add a target dependency use the `add_dependencies` command instead.

Answer (score 4):

I have not enough reputation to comment on Sakra answer...

One problem I see with that solution is that if you use any subdirectory the changes you do to the variable _allTargets inside the subdirectory will not be propagated to the parent scope.

Digging more, [list(append ...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:list) cannot be used in this case:

> Similar to the SET command, the LIST command creates new variable
>   values in the current scope, even if the list itself is actually
>   defined in a parent scope. To propagate the results of these
>   operations upwards, **use SET with PARENT_SCOPE, SET with CACHE
>   INTERNAL,** or some other means of value propagation.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:set :

> If PARENT_SCOPE is present, the variable will be set in the scope
>   above the current scope. **Each new directory or function creates a
>   new scope**. This command will set the value of a variable into the
>   parent directory or calling function (whichever is applicable to the
>   case at hand).

(note for myself: a macro **is not** a function)

I don't see a general solution (e.g. independent from using add_subdirectory) when using PARENT_SCOPE. However, here there seem to be a solution using CACHE INTERNAL.

Quoting from: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-November/018109.html

```
# A macro for passing lists between different directories
# through an internal cache variable.
MACRO (APPEND_INTERNAL_LIST  LIST_NAME  VALUE)

   # If the list in not in the cache, create it.
   IF (${LIST_NAME})
      SET (${LIST_NAME} "${${LIST_NAME}};${VALUE}" CACHE INTERNAL "Internal
variable")
   ELSE (${LIST_NAME})
      SET (${LIST_NAME} "${VALUE}" CACHE INTERNAL "Internal variable")
   ENDIF (${LIST_NAME})

ENDMACRO (APPEND_INTERNAL_LIST)

# A macro for passing lists between different directories
# through an internal cache variable.
# This function empties the variable (usually because of older runs)
MACRO (INITIALIZE_INTERNAL_LIST  LIST_NAME)
   SET (${LIST_NAME} "" CACHE INTERNAL "Internal variable")
ENDMACRO (INITIALIZE_INTERNAL_LIST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use CTest:

```
include(CTest)
if (BUILD_TESTING)
    add_test(MyTestName test.sh param1 param2)
endif(BUILD_TESTING)
```

Cmake will generate Makefile with new target **test**, see also: [Documentation for **add_test** command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aadd_test).

But you need to compile your project, before running tests:

```
make
make test
```

Also, you can use target **Experimental**, **Nightly**, or **Continuous**. These targets will compile project and run all tests, but they also tries to submit test results (you may configure it with **CTestConfig.cmake**).

Comment: Thanks. I tried using CTest and didn't like it because it didn't add the dependency and eats the output. This may be more appropriate if I didn't have an existing test infrastructure.