# cmake exclude executable during install

Tags: cmake

How to configure/hack cmake to build particular executable added with add_executable() but do not install it?

The executable is a unit test and will eventually be handled with add_test but for now I just want to strip test binaries off the release touching as little as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMake will only install an executable target if you apply the `install` function to it, i.e.:

```
 install(TARGETS ExecutableTest RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin")
```

To prevent the installation of the `ExecutableTest` for a `Release` build, add a `CONFIGURATIONS` restriction:

```
 install(TARGETS ExecutableTest RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin" CONFIGURATIONS Debug)
```

Alternatively, you can make `ExecutableTest` an optional target, which is not built by default:

```
add_executable(ExecutableTest EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${ExecutableTestFiles})
```

and then optionally only install the `ExecutableTest` if it has been built explicitly:

```
 install(TARGETS ExecutableTest RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin" OPTIONAL)
```

All optional test targets can be pooled in a super target to allow for building them in one step:

```
add_custom_target(MyTests DEPENDS ExecutableTest ExecutableTest2 ExecutableTest3)
```

Comment: I need it for both Debug and Release, so first suggestion, although feasible won't work. the one with optional target seems exactly what I want, am going to give it a try in a sec and will give this answer a chevron soon after.

Comment: The #2 did prevent tests from being built, Is there a way to group all these optional targets to be able to say "make mytests"?

Comment: shouldn't it be `add_custom_target(MyTests DEPENDS ExecutableTest ExecutableTest2 ExecutableTest3)`, so adding **DEPENDS** keyword?

Comment: @Antonio. Thanks for spotting the mistake. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL has [undefined behavior if combined with INSTALL](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:install) (cmake tries to warn you, it doesn't matter if OPTIONAL is set), a solution guaranteed to work is more complicated.

You should:

- [Remove dependency of "install" target to "all" target](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Various_Options) (once, in the main CMakeLists.txt):

  `set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY true)`
- Add OPTIONAL to the INSTALL statements in your test libraries. Be aware of the possible bug of CMake I reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201375/2436175)
- Collect separately all the targets you want to include in a custom "all_but_tests" 
  [CMake add_custom_target depending on whole project being built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372150/cmake-add-custom-target-depending-on-whole-project-being-built/17180923#17180923) (most difficult step)
- Create a [custom all_but_tests target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_custom_target):

  `add_custom_target(all_but_tests DEPENDS <<list of targets>>)`
- Add a dependency of the target install to all_but_tests

  `add_dependency(install all_but_tests)`

  (Sorry, this I have never tried, feedback is welcome)
- Create a [custom tests target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_custom_target):

  `add_custom_target(my_tests DEPENDS <<list of tests>>)`

Then (supposing you are using make, but will work also for ninja):

- You can call `make install`, which triggers `make all_but_tests`, and installs once built is complete.
- You can call `make my_tests`, and then `make install`, in this case it will install everything. You can concatenate the commands like this

  `make my_tests && make install`

  or, since there is not difference in this case:

  `make [all] && make install`

I was attracted by this question because I recently had to face a similar problem: [Installing only one target and its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17164731/2436175)

**Edit:**

`add_dependency(install all_but_tests)` will probably [not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163176/cmake-add-depedency-to-the-install-target).

So, either you [use an adequate workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8643015/2436175), or you call

`make all_but_tests && make install`

everytime you want to install "all_but_tests"