# CMake: Exclude custom install target(s) from 'make install [all]'

Tags: installation, cmake, target

I have a library that is built and linked to as part of my project. I want to provide the facility to OPTIONALLY have the library installed system-wide (or wherever ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} is set). Otherwise, by default, the project's final build products will be linked statically to the library, and the former get installed, but the library binaries stay in the build directory.

In other words:

```
$ make
$ make install
```

will build and install, the programs, but only something like

```
$ make install.foo
```

will install the library to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}, building it first if needed.

I have something like this so far (simplified from the actual script, so there might be errors):

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")
SET (FOO_LIBRARY "foo")

# Following builds library and makes it available to
# be linked other targets within project by:
# TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${progname} ${FOO_LIBRARY})
ADD_LIBRARY(${FOO_LIBRARY}
    foo/foo.cpp # and other sources ...
    )

###########################################################
# Approach #1
# -----------
# Optionally allow users to install it by invoking:
#
#       cmake .. -DINSTALL_FOO="yes"
#
# This works, but it means that users will have to run
# cmake again to switch back and forth between the libary
# installation and non-library installation.
#
OPTION(INSTALL_FOO "Install foo" OFF)
IF (INSTALL_FOO)
    INSTALL(TARGETS ${FOO_LIBRARY} DESTINATION lib/foo)
    SET(FOO_HEADERS foo/foo.h)
    INSTALL(FILES ${FOO_HEADERS} DESTINATION include/foo)
    UNSET(INSTALL_FOO CACHE)
ENDIF()
###########################################################

###########################################################
# Approach #2
# -----------
# Optionally allow users to install it by invoking:
#
#       make install.foo
#
# Unfortunately, this gets installed by "make install",
# which I want to avoid
SET(FOO_INSTALL "install.foo")
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${FOO_INSTALL}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -D COMPONENT=foo
        -P cmake_install.cmake)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${FOO_INSTALL} ${FOO_LIBRARY})
INSTALL(TARGETS ${FOO_LIBRRARY}
    DESTINATION lib/foo COMPONENT foo)
SET(FOO_HEADERS foo/foo.h)
INSTALL(FILES ${FOO_HEADERS}
    DESTINATION include/foo COMPONENT foo)
###########################################################
```

As can be seen, approach #1 sort of works, but the required steps to install the library are:

```
$ cmake .. -DINSTALL_FOO="yes"
$ make && make install
```

And then, to go back to "normal" builds, the user has to remember to run cmake again without the "-DINSTALL_FOO" option, otherwise the library will be installed on the next "make install".

The second approach works when I run "make install.foo", but it also install the library if I run "make install". I would like to avoid the latter.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track with approach #2. You can trick CMake into avoiding the installation of the `FOO` related files by using the `OPTIONAL` switch of the [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command.

For the `FOO` library target, the commands have to modified in the following way:

```
SET (FOO_LIBRARY "foo")
ADD_LIBRARY(${FOO_LIBRARY} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
    foo/foo.cpp 
    )
INSTALL(TARGETS ${FOO_LIBRARY}
    DESTINATION lib/foo COMPONENT foo OPTIONAL)
```

The `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` is added to `ADD_LIBRARY` to prevent the library from building when you run a plain `make`. The installation of `FOO_LIBRARY` is made optional by adding the `OPTIONAL` switch.

Making the installation of the `FOO_HEADERS` optional requires the following changes:

```
SET(FOO_HEADERS foo/foo.h)
SET(BINARY_FOO_HEADERS "")
FOREACH (FOO_HEADER ${FOO_HEADERS})
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FOO_HEADER}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FOO_HEADER} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FOO_HEADER}
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FOO_HEADER})
    LIST (APPEND BINARY_FOO_HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FOO_HEADER})
ENDFOREACH()
INSTALL(FILES ${BINARY_FOO_HEADERS}
    DESTINATION include/foo COMPONENT foo OPTIONAL)
```

The `FOREACH` loop sets up custom commands which copy the `FOO_HEADERS` verbatim to the corresponding binary dir. Instead of directly using the headers in the current source dir the `INSTALL(FILES ...` command picks up the copied headers from the binary dir. The paths of the headers in the binary dir are collected in the variable `BINARY_FOO_HEADERS`.

Finally the `FOO_INSTALL` target has to be set up in the following way:

```
SET(FOO_INSTALL "install.foo")
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${FOO_INSTALL}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -D COMPONENT=foo
        -P cmake_install.cmake
    DEPENDS ${BINARY_FOO_HEADERS})
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${FOO_INSTALL} ${FOO_LIBRARY})
```

The custom `FOO_INSTALL` is added with a dependency on `BINARY_FOO_HEADERS` to trigger the copying of the header files. A target level dependency on `FOO_LIBRARY` triggers the building of the library when you run `make install.foo`.

The solution however has the following drawbacks:

1. Upon configuring CMake will issues a warning `Target "foo" has EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL set and will not be built by default but an install rule has been provided for it.` CMake will however do the right thing anyway.
2. Once you have run `make install.foo` a subsequent `make install` command will also install all `FOO` related files, because the built `FOO` library and the headers exist in the binary directory.

Comment: Thanks @sakra. Will this result in FOO_LIBRARY being built automatically by default on a plain "make" if there are make targets that link against it?

Comment: Yes. Using `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` will result in FOO_LIBRARY being built.

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice to suppress the warnings for (1).

Comment: EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL has [undefined behavior if combined with INSTALL](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:install), even when combined with OPTIONAL: the warning is there for a good reason, this solution is not guaranteed to behave consistently.

Answer (score -1):

Check if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202096/2436175) works for you.

You would have to use different commands to those you said you would like to use, but I think it addresses the problem fairly well.